# How to Block Specific Countries from Accessing My Website? .Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1, webapi, .net-core-3.0, asp-net-core-spa-services

How to Block Specific Countries from Accessing My Website, also i need to know if there an API that returns countries with their updated IPs ? .Net Core

Comment: You can look at https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-dotnet, it will get country for specific IP, you can cache it for some time and prevent connection for it.

Comment: yeah, but I need the reverse, I need the IPs for countries

Comment: Why do you need all IPs? The list will be huge (a lot of memory). You can check IP of request and block it if it is from country that should be blocked.

Comment: All Ips will cost you 4*2^32 bytes for ipv4 and 8*2^64 bytes of RAM for ipv6, and Im still not mentioning the cost for updating terrabytes of IP addresses in memory every now and then. I highly doubt you NEED it - you don't need to develop and suppport your own GeoIP database for checking whether it is blocked or not or for performance reasons.

Comment: how can I block a specific country, should I know the IP range?

Answer (score 1):

Use [ASP.NET Core middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/) in conjunction with the free [GeoLite2 database](https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/) to block countries from your website.  An example of this can be found at [Kestrel WAF](https://github.com/mguinness/KestrelWAF#geolite2) where a rule can be defined in appsettings.json file.

```
{
  "MemberName": "IpCountry",
  "Operator": "IsInInput",
  "Inputs": [ "CN", "RU" ]
}
```